# Regex, can't exclude colon (:)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to exclude colon from my results.

**Example:**
Text Test: Look at this + example

I want to capture "Look at this" but `/([^:].*(?=+))/` is not working.

What am I missing? I want to capture everything after the colon (`:`) and before the plus sign.

Thanks

Comment: OMG, what was I doing wrong? LOL

Comment: Your regex as it is is invalid. You need to escape `+` like this: `\+`

Comment: Also, check out http://regex101.com/. It's super helpful to debug regexes.

Comment: THank you Maria! You we're both lifesavers :)

Comment: Another problem, now I have what I wan't but it has whitespace in the beggining and the end, how do I remove it?

Comment: How about `^\s*`?

Comment: I could use that but I wanted everything in the same regex, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
([^:]*(?=\+))


 you also need to put escape  ⬇  for + sign
                    ([^:].*(?=\+))
You do not need this dot ^
```

To answer your comment you can try this:

```
:\s*(.*?)\s*\+
```

You get your text in capture [group 1](https://regex101.com/r/DsKuU6/2)

```
<?php
$re = '/:\s*(.*?)\s*\+/';
$str = 'Text Test: Look at this   + example';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0];
?>
```

[Run it here](http://ideone.com/AWvHCd)

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DsKuU6/1)

Comment: THANK YOU! I was escaping the plus in my regex but I was adding the dot (.), it was the dot that was ruining the regex! Thank you!

Comment: Another problem, now I have what I wan't but it has whitespace in the beggining and the end, how do I remove it

Comment: Thank you Maverick, in my PHP script it returns with colon and the plus sign what am I doing wrong?

Comment: that is full match i guess, you should get your desired match in index 1 of your array